# Universal app with .@2x only

Tags: iphone, ios

My universal app has two storyBoards. One for iPhone and one for iPad. A lot of the code has been coded programatically and both storyBoards share the same ViewControllers. An example of how this works in view controller as follows:

```
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){ iPadInUse = YES;}
    else { iPadInUse = NO;}
```

So, if I have a image that needs to be displayed on both devices - I write the following:

```
       if (iPadInUse == YES) { recordViewImage = @"iPadRecordPanel@2x.png"
                             // x and y positions to adjusted accordingly }
               else {  recordViewImage = @"recordingPanel@2x.png"
                    //  // x and y positions to adjusted accordingly}
```

On the simulators everything works fine for all devices (retina /non retina). The only actual device I have is an iPhone 4S (all works fine). Is this ok what I'm doing as do not actually have any non retina images loaded fro non retina devices (all images suffix with @2x.png ??
Will my app get rejected because of this ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app will not get rejected, and everything will work fine.
But there are two issues:

1. On non-retina devices, App will load larger images. Which is not required there..so memory utilization will increase there without any outcome.
2. You don't need to write conditional code for iphone and ipad for setting images.
   You can use a tilde while naming the image files:

iPhone:

1. image@2x~iphone.png (retina only)
2. image@2x.png (retina only)
3. image~iphone.png
4. image.png

iPad:

1. image@2x~ipad.png (retina only)
2. image@2x.png (retina only)
3. image~ipad.png
4. image.png

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for late reply - can I ask, whats the difference between image@2x~iphone.png (retina only) and image@2x.png (retina only)??

Comment: Hi,  you can use image@2x.png if you are developing app for single device (for ipad only or for iphone only). If you are developing universal app, You should use image@2x~ipad.png and image@2x~iphone.png  and in code, you can use "image.png" name only. It will automatically load correct image for you.  ream more at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not ok.

On devices that do not have retinta screen more memory will be used to load the retina images.
You should always provide non retina and retina images and never load `@2x` images directly. iOS will load the correct image for you.

Answer (score 1):

It will not display proper image when you will give it name like iPadRecordPanel@2x.png. You can give name iPadRecordPanel.png and it will take 2x image of it from bundle. You can not give suffix with @2x. it will automatically identify proper image and display it.

Answer (score 1):

`No your app will not be rejected but you should not do this` because not providing non-retina images may decrease performance and image quality on older devices due to the required down-scale operations.

Hope it helps you.